# CSS Fixed Header Issue with body background

Tags: html, css, drupal, drupal-7

I am working on a Drupal-7 website using the openpublic theme.

I have modifed the css to make the header fixed, but when I scroll the page - the content scrolls over my navigation menu.  Can anyone tell me what needs done to prevent this?  The content also scrolls above my header.  I would like the content to stay below my header and menus.

I have chosen a specific page, because the template for the front-page is different.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it happened because your div position is set to fixed.

example

```
.div_class_name {

       position:fixed;

}
```

Changing the value might help.
You can use firebug(Firefox) or Chromebug(Chrome) to check your CSS .